# Date : Converting AM to PM, and PM to AM

Tags: actionscript-3

Perhaps a stupid question, but i really dont know the answer :(

lets say i have a date object, how can i change its AM date to PM, or vice verca?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems like you can

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var hours:uint = currentTime.getHours();
```

then you can say, if hours is greater than or equal to 12, then subtract by 12, otherwise, add 12 to it, for example, by

```
public static const millisecondsPerHour:int = 1000 * 60 * 60; 
var reversedAMPM = new Date(currentTime.getTime() + (12 * millisecondsPerHour));
```

Answer (score 2):

Although Jian's version should work, here's an alternative.
Assuming `var date:Date` is initialized, you may literally change it:

```
date.hours += (date.hours > 12) ? -12:12;
```

Comment: can literally change it? that's cool.  one catch is, will hour of 24 work? (and will it go to next day?)